# Pass table variable to SELECT function

Tags: php, if-statement, mysqli, prepared-statement

I have a `getData()` function, and a database with two tables: employers and members.
I would like to pass a variable containing the table name, so inside an "if" I could execute the appropriate SELECT statement. My problem I believe that after the "if" the `$stmt->bind_param();` doesn't know which `$stmt` to bind the take.
Any ideas on how I could achieve this?

Thanks

```
public function getData($table)
{
    if ($table == "employers")
    {
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM employers ");
    }
    else
    {
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM members ");
    } 

    $stmt->bind_param();
    if ($stmt->execute())
    {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
            { 
            $row = array_map('stripslashes', $row);
            $dataArray[] = $row;
            }
    }

    return $dataArray;      
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, since you aren't binding anything, that `->bind_param` method is superfluous. Just take that off.

```
public function getData($table)
{
    $dataArray = array();
    $t = ($table === 'employers') ? 'employers' : 'members';
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $t";
    $stmt = $this->link->prepare($query);
    if($stmt->execute()) {
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $row = array_map('stripslashes', $row);
            $dataArray[] = $row;
        }
    }

    return $dataArray;
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
$data = $aministrator_query->getData('members');
$tbody = '';
foreach($data as $row) {
    $tbody .= "<tr><td>{$row['user_id']}</td><td>{$row['user_password']}</td><td>{$row['user_first_name']}</td><td>{$row['user_last_name']}</td></tr>";
}
$table = sprintf('<table><thead><tr><th>ID</th><th>Password</th><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th></tr></thead><tbody>%s</tbody></table>', $tbody);
echo $table;
```

Comment: It makes sense but it still won't return the results. My code like this returns the results:

Comment: @Andrei i didn't understand what you meant in your comment. whats not working? how are you using the method?

Comment: It makes sense but it will still return values from the employers table even when I change the variable value from "employers" to "members"

$table = 'members';

$array = $administrator_query->getData($table);

Comment: There must be some other problem, maybe with my other table...ill check

Comment: @Andrei are you sure this is the only code inside that method? change it to identity instead `===`

Comment: @Gost This is the main function, that works for employers and displays the results when called but doesn't work for members. Weird.
Sorry don't know how to put code in the comments...

             public function getData()
       {

  $stmt = $this->link->prepare("SELECT * FROM employers");
  $stmt->bind_param();
  if ($stmt->execute())
  {
      $result = $stmt->get_result();
      while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC))
       { 
       $row = array_map('stripslashes', $row);
    $dataArray[] = $row;
       }
  } 
  return $dataArray;  
         }

Comment: I just noticed, that If the table where I am trying to display what the function is returning is creating the rows for the actual data coming, but it's not displaying it. I am looking into this now.

Comment: @Andrei sure haven't used this answer at all, comparing to what the comments states

Comment: I tried your answer. I also had a getData function above that worked to get and display values for employers. The only thing is that when I try to change FROM members instead of employers I just get the empty number of rows and I want to find what is wrong. Don't know if you understand what I meen.

Comment: No they are not. I had a record there. When I called the function, there was 1 row in the table that was empty. I added a new record to the table, then I run the function again, and now there where 2 empty rows. Really strange...

Comment: This is How I am displaying the data.

$array = $administrator_query->getData();

 echo "<table border= 1px><br>"; // start a table tag in the HTML
 echo "<tr>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Password</th>
      <th>First Name</th>  
      <th>Last Name</th>
       </tr>";

 foreach ($array as $row) 
 {
 echo 
 "<tr>
  <td>" . $row['user_id'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row['user_password'] . "</td>
  <td>" . $row['user_first_name'] .  "</td>
  <td>" . $row['user_last_name'] .  "</td>
 </tr>";  //$row['index'] the index here is a field name
 } 
 echo "</table>";